# Docker container cannot resolve website names, but can ping their ip

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dns, iptables, resolve

When I tried to

`apt-get update`

in a container based on ubuntu.

I got an error like this.

```
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'.
```

When I tried to ping the ip of 'archive.ubuntu.com', it's ok.

But when I tried to ping 'archive.ubuntu.com', it showed me

```
uknown host archive.ubuntu.com
```

So I tried several ways I can find on the internet, like this.

```
echo "91.189.92.201 archive.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Then I can ping 'archive.ubuntu.com'

But other websites are still not linkable by name.

I tried to add a line to /etc/default/docker, like this

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 114.114.114.114 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

Then i restart docker service, and attach to the container, to see this

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

and the results

```
root@d9d5bbdb11de:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I don't know if that works for it.

ps, i can ping 8.8.8.8, 114.114.114.114, 8.8.4.4.

For some reasons, I tried to figure it out where it is a firewall problem, so i used iptables out of the containers.

`iptables-save.`

And here are the results when I iptables-save out of containers.

```
wjy@wjy-VirtualBox:~$ sudo iptables-save [sudo] wjy 的密码： 

# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Mar  4 16:06:53 2017

*nat :PREROUTING ACCEPT [28:1772] :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [253:15867] :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [253:15867] :DOCKER - [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER

-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER

-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE

-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN COMMIT

# Completed on Sat Mar  4 16:06:53 2017

# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sat Mar  4 16:06:53 2017

*filter :INPUT ACCEPT [1211:567114] :FORWARD DROP [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [1254:152567] :DOCKER - [0:0] :DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]

-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN COMMIT

# Completed on Sat Mar  4 16:06:53 2017
```

It may be a host, dns or iptable problem. But I don't know what to do to make all my containers resolve the website names and link to the internet.
If you met the similar situation or know how to solve it, please do me a favour.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jianjian feng details, thank you.

Comment: @jbadua Do you still know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented exactly that error staying behind a proxy on the host machine. I mean, if your docker host machine have set proxy settings. I'll explain how I solved it, maybe could be useful to you if is your case or useful to others.

There are 3 places to configure proxy settings:

- At OS level:

It depends of the O.S., usually you can put `http_proxy=http://yourproxy:port/` at `/etc/environment`

- At Docker engine level:

You must create folder and file at `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` containing:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxy:port/"
```

- And the last one (don't forget to reboot after last two steps), you must put it also as environment var on `Dockerfile` to build it!!

Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://yourproxy:port/
RUN apt-get update
```

Maybe this is your problem like mine was.

My advise is don't touch iptables and don't touch DNS. Recreating containers docker do the needed jobs itself automatically. If you need to touch there, something went wrong. Only be sure to have internet access fully working on docker host machine.

Good luck.

Comment: 1.how can i get "yourproxy" and "port" at my machine and docker? or is is just put those words in those files?

Comment: 2.what should i do to make sure my container link the internet if i don't want to use dockerfile to run, aka.  just start  and attach to a container

Comment: 3. i think i didn't touch proxy things on my os.

Comment: No, you mustn't put "yourproxy" there. You must put the ip address and the port number. But from the docker container is the same proxy you are using on your host machine, is not special. So this solution is not valid for you if you are not using proxy settings. I guess reading the point 3 of your comment that you are not behind a proxy, so this is not valid for you. Sorry.

Comment: so you met the same problem because you were using proxy setting at that time?